# Como almacenar en un nuevo elemento el codigo generado al hacer click() con htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

Estoy tratando de crear un pequeño crawler que coga datos desde soccerway.com.

El caso es que soy bastante novato con la programacion y mucho mas con htmlunit, consigo trabajar mas o menos bien con la web antes de tener intereaccion con la web, pero para poder raspar datos necesito coger el codigo que se crea al hacer click sobre los nombres de cada liga, es decir:

Al entrar en soccerway (homepage) te aparece un listado completo de los partidos del dia, y solo algunas ligas, las mas importantes, estan desplegadas, en el resto aparecen los partidos del dia con la hora del partido, al hacer click sobre el nombre de la liga.

Como podria hacer click y coger el codigo que se genera tras esto? Viendo el codigo fuente se ve perfectamente que aparece nuevo codigo.

Gracias!

Edito para añadir el codigo con el que estoy trabajando

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60);
final HtmlPage soccerway = webClient.getPage("https://es.soccerway.com/matches/2019/08/26/");

 List <HtmlElement> all = new ArrayList <HtmlElement> ();
 all = soccerway.getByXPath("//tr[contains(@class, 'clickable')]");

 System.out.println(all.get(20).asText()); //Con esto testeo que recupere un tr cualquiera (20) para probar la interaccion, y lo recupera bien, el problema viene despues...

 List <HtmlElement> all = new ArrayList <HtmlElement> ();
 all = soccerway.getByXPath("//tr[contains(@stage-value, '15')]"); 
 // aunque recupero solo un tr con este codigo, lo meto en un array porque en el futuro deberia recuperar muchos de una misma pagina, asi que es tonteria hacer un cast

 final HtmlPage oneclick = all.get(0).click();
 System.out.println(oneclick.asText()); //aqui se supone que deberia devolverme la web una vez hago click sobre ese tablerow y activa la interaccion en ajax para mostrar el codigo nuevo, el cual contiene lo que me interesa, los partidos dentro del listado una vez clicas en el pais
```

Pero no funciona, me devuelve la misma pagina que al principio, sin el agregado que surge con la interaccion al hacer click en el navegador real.

```
 System.out.println(oneclick); //al ejecutar este comando, me muestra la url seguido de un @y.un.numero.random
```

Ser novato me priva de tener mas conocimiento, trato de aprender, y para aprender lo mejor es programar para crear cosas para uno mismo.

Comment: Hola @Jmd, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. Por favor, completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla. Saludos.